# FFmpeg ProRes RAW support?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to find a definitive answer on if ProResRAW is supported by ffmpeg.  When trying to probe a ProResRAW file it gives an error saying it is an unsupported codec.

Here is the stream info:

```
Stream #0:1(eng): Video: none (aprn / 0x6E727061), none(progressive), 8224x4336, 2339415 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 514:271, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 24k tbc (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2024-06-08T03:35:14.000000Z
  vendor_id       : appl
  encoder         : Apple ProRes RAW
```

Comment: Why are you not trusting what the software tells you? // That being said, `aprn` is not an approved MP4 codec identifier anyway.

Comment: Just curious if anyone had any other information out there...thanks!

Comment: It’s also entirely possible for your specific ffmpeg build to not support it. You do not mention anything about it, the version, or the operating system you’re on.

Comment: Probably this codec will never be implemented in ffmpeg because of copyright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Romeo Ninov said -- probably will never be implemented due to copyright.